# Caching Results in a Static Variable

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, caching, entity-framework-4, static

I'm using a Linq query to retrieve entities from an SQL server using the Entity Framework. When I update an entitiy, the EF is caching the result. I suspect this is because the ObjectContext is in a static variable (below). The only way to refresh the data using my code below is to call a method and set `_db` to `null` when there might be stale data displayed (Eg: in a GridView). Is there a way to just prevent it from caching, or to add some sort of end request handler to call this method on my data layer instead of needing to detect when there may be stale data displayed?

```
private static ServiceEntities _db;
protected static ServiceEntitiesDb
    {
        get
        {
            if (_db == null)
            {
                _db = new ServiceEntities();
                _db.Contacts.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges; // failed
            }
            return _db;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Contact> GetContactsByName(string name) {
        var items = Db.Contacts;
        var filteredName = items.Where(i => (i.Name??string.Empty).IndexOf(name) >=0);
        return filteredName;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason about you're doing the Object Context static?

Comment: So I don't have to recreate it and wrap every method with a `using` block.

Comment: But you can use the variable without the using. In fact i'm always using the DBContext but not static, and override the dispose method to avoid performance problems. The reason for the caching it's because `_db` to be a static variable and you instance the reference only once, keeping the the reference in the entirely life of cycle

Comment: _So I don't have to recreate it and wrap every method with a using block_ ... So you rather wrap every method with a check whether there is stale data and a refresh if there is. o_O.  Just don't use a static context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slightly verbose solution (which I wanted to avoid) is to wrap it in a using block. Ie:

```
public static IEnumerable<Contact> GetContactsByName(string name) {
        var items = Db.Contacts;
        var filteredName = items.Where(i => (i.Name??string.Empty).IndexOf(name) >=0);
        return filteredName;
}
```

Becomes

```
public static IEnumerable<Contact> GetContactsByName(string name) {
    using (var db = new SomeContext()) {
        var items = db.Contacts;
        var filteredName = items.Where(i => (i.Name??string.Empty).IndexOf(name) >=0);
        return filteredName;
    }
}
```